# SonarQube default credentials for internal H2 db?

Tags: sonarqube, h2, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube5.6

I'm running SonarQube 5.6.1 and am trying to save a view that I created. To do that, I want to take a peek at H2 DB that Sonar (according to it's own readme) uses for internal embedded DB.

I've ran the H2 jar file and in console was able to log in to dummy DB. If SonarQUbe is running, I can't connect.

So, what are default credentials for that DB?
Tried my user credentials and admin/admin, none work. Admin/admin is default for SonarQube administrator user.

Comment: Note that the SonarQube DB should be treated as a black box.

Comment: Note that the H2 DB is NOT production ready

Comment: I fully get it. Just trying things out, not planning to build anything long-lasting.

Comment: I also cannot get admin/admin to work as described on https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Get+Started+in+Two+Minutes

Comment: sonar/sonar login does not work either.  Note: I'm using 6.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default values are *sonar/sonar* .

**Edit**: this was answered at the time of SonarQube 5.6.x. Recent versions (e.g. v6.7 LTS) might have changed to empty username/password (for embedded database).

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I use sonarqube 6.7.3. Says
Wrong user name or password [28000-176] 28000/28000

Comment: What worked for me was an empty username and an empty password! :-)

Comment: Thanks, answer fine-tuned accordingly

Answer (score 6):

For the config below (**openjdk-11**, **sonarqube-8**), follow the steps:

- Change directory to /opt/sq/lib/jdbc/h2

  `cd /opt/sq/lib/jdbc/h2`
- Run the command line below to open h2 shell

  `java -cp h2-1.3.176.jar org.h2.tools.Shell`

you will be prompted to fill the following:

- **URL** jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
- **Driver** org.h2.Driver
- **User** blank or 'sonar'
- **Password** blank or 'sonar'

Answer (score 2):

Here are instructions for SonarQube v8.4.2:

After logging in to SonarQube with administration credentials (admin/admin, if you downloaded the vanilla installation), then you can navigate from the top menu labeled "Administration", click on "System", click on "System" drop-down box, and look for the Database section. You will find "user" and "URL". Confirm this is what you expect.

In my default installation, I used the following to log into the H2 console (after ensuring my SonarQube instance is up, I had to restart it since it had been running too long also, I think it must have stalled):

```
Driver Class: org.h2.Driver
JDBC URL: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
```

**There is no username and password needed.** If you want to set one, then you can modify the `sonar.jdbc.username` and `sonar.jdbc.password` properties in the `your-sonarqube-installation-directory/conf/sonar.properties` file. Here's a snippet of it:

```
# User credentials.
# Permissions to create tables, indices and triggers must be granted to JDBC user.
# The schema must be created first.
#sonar.jdbc.username=
#sonar.jdbc.password=

#----- Embedded Database (default)
# H2 embedded database server listening port, defaults to 9092
#sonar.embeddedDatabase.port=9092
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using sonar 6.5 and username password was default values. **username is sa without any password**.
I was able to backup database using following command (from sonar home directory):

```
java -cp lib/jdbc/h2/h2-1.3.176.jar org.h2.tools.Script -url jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
```

which is the same as:

```
java -cp lib/jdbc/h2/h2-1.3.176.jar org.h2.tools.Script -url jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar -user sa
```

Also if server is down, you still can access database using:

```
-url jdbc:h2:<SONAR_HOME>/data/sonar -user sa
```

Answer (score 0):

Default is admin/admin version 7.1. Installed using brew.

Comment: This is referring to SonarQube server login, not the H2 database login of SonarQube. There is no username or password needed by default for internal H2 database login.