# What is the default sonar database?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I'm trying to reset the admin password of my SonarQube and I have already found that is executing the following query:

```
update users set crypted_password = '88c991e39bb88b94178123a849606905ebf440f5', salt='6522f3c5007ae910ad690bb1bdbf264a34884c6d' where login = 'admin'
```

But the thing is that I don't know what is the database manager where I need to execute it and how to connect to it. When I installed my SonarQube and my SonarQube Scanner I didn't specified any database manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only "default" SonarQube database is the embedded H2 database, which is provided **solely for initial testing**. It is neither intended nor supported for production use. You **will not** be able to upgrade with this database. As a large red banner should be telling you at the bottom of every single page in the SonarQube interface.

But okay, to answer your question, you can use any generic client to make this update. I generally use [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) on the rare occasions I need to peer into **the black box** that is the SonarQube database.

Comment: sorry to bother you but i have one more question. what are the credentials to connect to the database?

Comment: I solved the problem, in my case was with password and username empty as suggested in the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39207108/sonarqube-default-credentials-for-internal-h2-db thank you very much! :D